# Predicting geographic location in R?

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, regression

I am very new to the world of GIS and spatial statistics, but I have a very large dataset consisting of many points with geographic coordinates and a bunch of other variables for every point. I managed to read in this dataset as a SpatialPointsDataframe in R, with all the extra variables as data attributes, and do all kinds of fun stuff with it.

One of the things that I would like to do, but haven't been able to figure out how, is predict the latitude/longitude coordinates of a certain point based on the variables I have for that point.

If I wanted to predict just a one-dimensional variable, I could take for example 90% of the dataset, and then estimate the effect sizes of all the variables I have measured in a linear regression. Let's say I had three continuous variables, and fitted this model:

```
y = b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x3 + error
```

I now know the effect sizes (b1, b2, and b3) of the three continuous variables (x1, x2, x3), and can now use these to predict y for the remainig 10% of my datapoints, for which I have x1, x2, and x3 measured.

If I want y to be a geographic location, so a combination of longitude and latitude, how could I go about doing this?

Comment: Let me see if I get it: say you're using variable pluviosity. There are places where there's few rain, places where there's lots of rain. So, from a value of "how much rain falls in a place", you want to get this place? I don't think that's possible. There are many places where it rains too few, and many places where it rains too much, and this does not go in a linear way!

Comment: Yes @Rodrigo, something like that! But I have multiple variables. If you only have rain, it's going to be very difficult, I agree. If you have rain combined with more variables, e.g. temperature, humidity, population density, wild life, etc, it should become possible to predict the location with some level of confidence I would think.

Comment: You're right, that sounds possible. I wonder if some modeling program (like Maxent) can be of any help... Or you can try a more direct approach, like the one I'll sketch below.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this by first kriging your variables to give a surface S(x,y) and then working out the areas of high probabilities of S(x,y)=V where V is the value of the variable at your mystery point. Do this multivariately if your variables are correlated, or assume independence and combine the probabilities...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your variables are in different rasters (preferably with the same extension and resolution):

```
r1 #temperature
r2 #pluviosity
r3 #population density
...
```

Now you have the values you want to look:

```
r1.v = 30 # Celsius degrees
r2.v = 700 # mm
r3.v = 100 # inhabitants/sq. km.
```

You may modify your rasters to only keep those (or close) values:

```
r1[r1 < 29 & r1 > 31] <- NA
r2[r2 < 690 & r2 > 710] <- NA
r3[r3 < 95 & r3 > 105] <- NA
```

Finally, you may try to merge/multiply/add the modified rasters, and see where there are values remaining (there's your solution):

```
rFinal <- overlay(r1, r2, r3, fun=function(x,y,z){return(x+y+z)})
```

This should leave you with values only where your original rasters didn't have a NA.

Comment: This seems to overlook that the OP is trying to predict values from a *regression model.*  That's quite a bit different than selecting values from raster data.

Comment: @whuber If you know how to do it, show it yourself. I understood that a regression model was just an example of method that could work. The question is "Predicting geographic location in R?"

Comment: I know a large number of methods, ranging from multivariate regression through various machine learning techniques.  But what I know (or don't know) how to do should have no bearing on the quality or appropriateness of your post, should it?

Comment: @whuber I don't know. I'm just trying to help. And up to now nobody offered another solution.

Comment: @whuber I think its more like the inverse of a regression model: given `Y = beta X + N(0,s)` and data {(X,Y)}, find [X|Y], in linear model terms.

Answer (score 1):

Having world experts in spatial statistics on my corridor is very useful. This seems to be your exact problem:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211675314000608

The code is now on GitLab, but is under development. It currently only works on a unit square, and I'm not sure it can handle covariates in the model:

https://gitlab.com/b-rowlingson/revkrig

Also, there are a few tuning parameters and nothing is really documented. Please follow the project for updates.

Comment: This looks very relevant indeed! Thank you so much! It would be very helpful if you could find out if there is some usable code for this :) Thanks again!

Comment: No code released, but E Giorgi can send me it, and I'll see if I can get a release as a package. Interestingly, its easy for one prediction point, but if you have two then if you think about it knowing where one is (even with uncertainty) affects where you think the second one is. So solving for more than one point is.... complicated!

Comment: Thank you! I will give this article a detailed read this weekend :)

Comment: So, does this method/code allow for a vector of Y's, i.e., multiple predictors?

Comment: Any news on the R-code yet? :)